# Error Generation While upgrading the OpenERP Module

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

Error is generated while i am upgrading my module in OpenERP

```
res_model not found error
```

**Error:**

**Client Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
        response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 993, in load
        menu_root_ids = self.get_user_roots(req)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 979, in get_user_roots
        return Menus.search(menu_domain, 0, False, False, req.context) File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
        result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
        result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send 
      raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)
```

**Server Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
        return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
        result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
        res = fn(db, uid, *params)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
        return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
        return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
        res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
        return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/mail/mail_group_menu.py", line 44, in search
        ids = super(ir_ui_menu, self).search(cr, uid, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=False)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py", line 127, in search
        result = self._filter_visible_menus(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py", line 103, in _filter_visible_menus
        if not menu.child_id:
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 497, in __getattr__
        return self[name]
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 405, in __getitem__
        field_values = self._table.read(self._cr, self._uid, ids, field_names, context=self._context, load="_classic_write")
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3621, in read
        result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3742, in _read_flat
        res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, values=res)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 538, in get
        ids2 = obj.pool.get(self._obj).search(cr, user, domain + [(self._fields_id, 'in', ids)], limit=self._limit, context=context)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/mail/mail_group_menu.py", line 44, in search
        ids = super(ir_ui_menu, self).search(cr, uid, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=False)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py", line 127, in search
        result = self._filter_visible_menus(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py", line 103, in _filter_visible_menus
        if not menu.child_id:
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 499, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(e)
    AttributeError: 'Field res_model not found in browse_record(ir.actions.act_window, 494)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather ambiguous question.

What version of openERP is in problem here?

In OE7, only ir_act_window has res_model, I don't even see model that you provided (ir.actions.act_window). Same in OE8.

If you could specify what is going, is this your module/extension? It would help a lot.

Comment: I'm using OpenERP 7. Suddenly on updating a module i found this issue.Exact error is     raise AttributeError(e)
AttributeError: 'Field res_model not found in browse_record(ir.actions.act_window, 494)'

Comment: Ok. Where do you use this browse? Error raise gives you line where error occurred etc. Is this your code or?

Comment: I've update my error.I'm getting that error when ever i login in OpenERP or upgrade a module in OpenERP.

Comment: Whenever you try to login OE first starts update since it failed last time. What did you change in your module? Or did you change in openerp files something?

Comment: I don't know about module,but i didn't change anything in OpenERP files

Comment: In that case I suggest that you download new openerp source. If you use only openerp modules thee shouldn't be any errors but it happends. If you are trying to build your own modules you need to be really carefull. 
In any case, try to download new source and try procedure again, it should be alright.

Comment: I have done all those ,but still the error is coming. I don't know where i had screwed it up.

Comment: I got fix for my problem.I had deleted an xml file for which a menu is created.It is causing the problem.After i delete that menu item.My error got resolved.Anyways thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have deleted a xml file for which menu item is created.As i have deleted the file,the menu item is searching for it and it is throwing the error.So finally i resolved the issue by deleting the Menu item.